# Display Box on mouseover for DOM Element? (With variable data) jQuery UI?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Simply put, I'm creating a script to run through like 100 different elements. Then, for each element, create an box that pops up on mouseover. The information displayed in the box would be unique to each element.

I figured I could loop through every element, then create the element1.onmouseover = function(){} for every element.

Can I do this (should I) with jQuery as I've seen recommended elsewhere? What tools can I use to create/style the box uniquely? (CSS requires me to have my data pre-written in the HTML section to display it right?)

Code:

```
for (var index = 0;index < numProf;index++) {
    if (document.getElementById('MTG_INSTR$' + index) != "staff") {
        document.getElementById('MTG_INSTR$' + index).onmouseover = function(){

        }
    }
}
```

The HTML Looks like:

```
<span class="PSLONGEDITBOX" id="MTG_INSTR$0">FIRSTNAME LASTNAME</span>
```

So I want to create a box, on hover, that displays the name and a link to some page. (like www.google.com/firstname_lastname for example)

Comment: Why don't you try and let us know what the problem(s) were?

Comment: Hey Lee Taylor, I really am new to JS so I'm not sure where to begin. Is this something I can do with jQuery UI? Just inside of a loop where I identify every element tIhen create the function to create the hover box? Would this idea work? And jQuery UI is a good way to solve it? I'm going in blind.

Comment: Warm welcome to SO. Please show that HTML you're talking about, because *`"some elements"`* means nothing meaningful. Add to your question some JS of what you tried already. Before you do so please get in common of how this site works by taking a [tour], reading [ask] and than try to create a [mcve].

Comment: Will edit in. Thanks.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan fixed it. You caught me mid edit. Busted!

Comment: Hummm sorry but I cannot see any box, nor HTML, nor CSS, nor JS code of what you tried...

Answer (score 0):

You don't need necessarily a for loop, you can go directly and target

> every element which ID **starts with** `[id^=]` with advanced attribute selector

Say we have `<span>` elements with **ID starting with `MTG_INSTR$`** and some number like

```js
function doMyStuff() {

  // Get text content
  var text = this.textContent;
  
  // Do nothing if contains "staff" "Staff" "stAFf" etc
  if(/staff/i.test(text)) return; 
  
  var num = this.id.replace(/\D+/,""); // Get the suffix number (if you need it)
  console.log("ID SUFFIX: "+ num );
  
  var googleLink = "http://www.google.com/search?q="+ encodeURIComponent(text.trim());
  console.log(googleLink);
  // window.location = googleLink; // uncomment to navigate to page
}


Array.from( document.querySelectorAll("[id^='MTG_INSTR$']") ).forEach( el => {
  el.addEventListener("click", doMyStuff);
});
```

```css
[id^="MTG_INSTR$"] {
    color:red;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
Lorem ipsum <span id="MTG_INSTR$7">dolor sit amet</span>, consectetur 
adipisicing elit. <span id="MTG_INSTR$23">Fuga maxime officia</span> asperiores 
repellat cumque <span id="MTG_INSTR$31">magnam molestiae <b>Staff</b> will not 
react to click!!!!! </span>suscipit recusandae! Perferendis repudiandae iste 
maxime dolores <span id="MTG_INSTR$50">tempora nostrum</span>, atque dolorum 
<span id="MTG_INSTR$545">ipsam</span>! Pariatur, error.
```

Comment: Is there a performance difference in using a for loop or this method? I'll give it a shot. Totally new to JS, so I'll be looking into this. For creating an event listener for a "hover" event, do I need to then create one for onmouseover and onmouseleave? And for the UI what do you recommend?

Comment: Also, with this foreach method, how do I specify options for mouseover and mouseexit? Prior to, I could just assign those options. In addition to your "click", how do I format that?